# Como sobrescrever um método via prototype num objeto JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, objetos

Estou estudando JavaScript, mas especificamente **Parasitic Combination Inheritance**, e me deparei com a sobrescrita de métodos. Acontece que criei o seguinte código:

```
var Base = function(nome, texto) {
    this.name = nome;
    this.text = texto;
    this.saudacao = function() {
          return this.text + ' ' + this.name;
    }
}

var heranca = function(p, f) {
    var pc = Object.create(p.prototype);
    f.prototype = pc;
    f.prototype.constructor = f;
}

var Dia = function(texto) {
    Base.call(this, 'Fulano? ', 'Tudo bem, ');
    this.newText = texto;
}
heranca(Base, Dia);
Dia.prototype.saudacao = function() {
    var msg = this.saudacao();
    return msg + ' ' + this.newText;
}

var ola = new Dia('Bom dia!');
alert(ola.saudacao());
```

Ao executar `alert(ola.saudacao())`, tenho o retorno da classe pai, não da sobrescrita.

Para teste, alterei o nome do método `saudacao` da classe `Dia` para `novaSaudacao` e, executando `alert(ola.novaSaudacao())`, consigo a saída correta.

Aparentemente o código escrito em `Dia.prototype.saudacao = function() {//código...}` nem chega a ser executado, adicionei um `alert('!')` nele e isso não surtiu efeito.

Daí vem a pergunta: como trabalhar corretamente com a sobrescrita de métodos em javascript sem se esquecer do **Parasitic Combination Inheritance**?

#### EDIT

Vou tentar explicar a aplicação prática para esclarecer um pouco a questão. Os objetos usados como exemplo não estão em questão, apenas suas funcionalidades.

Considere uma classe que se chame `Gentileza` e possui o método `Saudacao`.

Ao criar...

```
var ola = new Gentileza("José");
```

Podemos executar...

```
ola.Saudacao();
```

E teremos como resultado: `"Olá, José."`.

Agora, precisamos de dois outros objetos chamados `Dia` e `Noite` que são filhos de `Gentileza`. Então podemos criar...

```
var dia = new Dia("José");
```

E executar...

```
dia.Saudacao();
```

Agora, a mensagem será `"Olá, José. Bom dia!"`.

A primeira parte da mensagem (`"Olá, José."`) foi gerada no objeto pai `Gentileza`.
O objeto `Dia` herdou a saudação do objeto pai e adicionou `"Bom dia!"` ao texto.

**Para fins de conclusão**: pretendo que minha classe filho herde um método da classe pai e o complemente.

Comment: O que pretende com a linha `var msg = this.saudacao();` ? Não consegui perceber no seu código...

Comment: Qual o retorno final que você quer?

Comment: **BrnPer** A variável "msg" contém o texto recuperado da classe-pai. Uso logo abaixo adicionando um texto para complementar a saudação e incluir um "bom dia". Poderia ser também return this.saudacao() + ' ' + this.newText.

Comment: **FabianoLothor**, o retorno deve ser: "Tudo bem, Fulano? Bom dia!"

Comment: A sua classe pai cria um método que "sobrescreve" (*shadows*) o que estiver no prototype. Parece que você está entendendo ao contrário, mas não está muito clara a pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acho que entendi o que está te confundindo. As operações que você faz, em resumo, são:

1. Estabelece herança de classe `base` para classe `dia` (nota: é convenção usar iniciais maiúsculas para nome de classes ou funções construtoras, mas você usou minúsculas)
2. Cria um novo método `saudacao` no protótipo de `dia`.
3. Cria instância de `dia` e executa o método `saudacao` dela.

A sua lógica é que `dia.prototype.saudacao` deve sobrescrever o método de saudação já existente na base. Isso seria verdadeiro se o método estivesse no protótipo de `base`. Porém, ele é criado na instância (`this`):

```
this.saudacao = function() {
      return this.text + ' ' + this.name;
}
```

E o construtor de `dia` força a execução do construtor de `base`:

```
base.call(this, 'Fulano? ', 'Tudo bem, ');
```

Assim, o método `saudacao` executado em `ola.saudacao()` é o definido dentro do construtor `base`, não o que está em `dia.prototype`.

Métodos presentes na instância sempre têm prioridade em relação ao que estiver na cadeia de protótipos. Quando você executa `ola.saudacao`, a primeira coisa que é verificada é se o próprio objeto `ola` possui uma propriedade `saudacao`. E ele possui, por causa daquela chamada `base.call(this, ...)`. Então esse é executado. Somente se ele não existisse é que seria verificado `dia.prototype` e depois `base.prototype`.

Você conseguiria o resultado que quer com o seguinte código:

```js
var Base = function(nome, texto) {
    this.name = nome;
    this.text = texto;
}

Base.prototype.saudacao = function() {
  return this.text + ' ' + this.name;
}

var heranca = function(p, f) {
    var pc = Object.create(p.prototype);
    f.prototype = pc;
    f.prototype.constructor = f;
}

var Dia = function(texto) {
    Base.call(this, 'Fulano? ', 'Tudo bem, ');
    this.newText = texto;
}

heranca(Base, Dia);

Dia.prototype.saudacao = function() {
    var msg = Base.prototype.saudacao.call(this);
    return msg + ' ' + this.newText;
}

var ola = new Dia('Bom dia!');
alert(ola.saudacao());
```

Porém não me parece uma boa maneira. É que parece que você quer fazer duas coisas ao mesmo tempo: sobrescrever um método, mas ao mesmo tempo ter acesso ao método sobrecrito de dentro do método que o sobrescreve. Parece mais caso para composição de funções ao estilo funcional do que caso para uso de herança.

Comment: Creio que não, isso que você falou faria sentido se ao invés de fazer `dia.prototype.saudacao =` ele fizesse `base.prototype.saudacao =` e funcionasse, no caso o prototype não está sendo sobrescrito, por algum motivo.

Comment: @FabianoLothor fico com você. A minha intenção era, **após** herdar os métodos e propriedades da classe `base` (peço desculpas pelo minúsculo), sobrescrever o método usando `dia.prototype.saudacao = ...`, como mencionou. Mas, não sendo assim, então, como sobrescrever o método declarado no pai, agora no filho?

Comment: Estou dando uma verificada @Leikovsk, fiquei curioso agora também.

Comment: @Leikovsk Acrescentei mais informação na resposta, veja se agora está mais claro

Comment: @bfavaretto Fiz uma alteração no código e retirei o método da instância. Também entendi o que o @FabianoLothor quis dizer sobre chamar `this.saudacao` dentro de `Dia.prototype.saudacao`. O problema foi resolvido usando todas as dicas daqui. Vou colocar o código reescrito e comentar.

Answer (score 2):

Tá, eu entendi o que você quer fazer.

Mas está bastante confuso o `"como"` você está fazendo.

Enfim, pelo que entendi o que você está querendo saber é:

> Como sobrescrevo o `prototype` de um objeto pai, na classe filha.

Antes de resolver isso, o ideal é você entender como se usa Orientação à Objetos corretamente, porque está muito confuso o exemplo e o porque de algumas coisas estarem sendo feitas de maneira X ao invés de Y.

Enfim, tem uma inconsisência grande no código abaixo.

**Veja só:**

```
Dia.prototype.saudacao = function() {
    var msg = this.saudacao();
    return msg + ' ' + this.newText;
}
```

Você está - tentando - sobrescrever um método e - sem perceber - está criando um loop infinito, de forma recursiva.

De qualquer forma, entendi o que você estava tentando fazer ali em cima.

**Mude para algo assim:**

```
Dia.prototype.saudacao = function() {
    return this.text + ' ' + this.name + ' ' + this.newText;
}
```

Agora em relação a solução, o problema está em algum lugar da método `heranca`:

A forma como você está fazendo é que está causando todo esse problema no código, a sobrecarga de métodos funciona normalmente se feita da maneira `"padrão"`.

A função herança não deve estar fazendo o que esperávamos que ela fizesse, de modo que ficou impossível de resolver essa questão sem modificar muito o código que você fez.

Acabei refazendo o código, basicamente ele faz a mesma coisa e aqui ele funciona bem.

```
function Greet ( name , text ) {
    // Sobre o que falei acima de orientação a objetos, não vejo sentido do "nome" da pessoa estar nessa Classe. (só um exemplo)

    this._name = name ;
    this._text = text ;
    this._greet = function () {
        return this._text + ' ' + this._name ;
    }
}

function GoodDay ( greet ) {
    this.prototype = Greet ;

    Greet.call( this , 'Fulano? ' , 'Tudo bem, ' );

    this._greet = greet ;
}

GoodDay.prototype._greeting = function () {
    return this._text + ' ' + this._name + ' ' + this._greet ;
}

var hello = new GoodDay( 'Bom dia!' ) ;

alert( hello._greeting() ) ;
```

Quebrei muito a cabeça para tentar manter essa função `heranca` que você criou, mas não consegui resolver com ela.

De qualquer forma, se você analisar a situação e pensar de forma Orientada a Objetos, vai ver que não faz muito sentido ter uma função que atribuí as heranças entre cada classe.

Por exemplo: um cachorro, ele **`É`** um animal (isso é imutável), não precisa alguém chegar e dizer que o cachorro vai ser um animal e é basicamente isso que você está fazendo com essa função `heranca`.

Não sei se ficou muito claro, mas é +/- isso que estou querendo explicar.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Você tem razão quanto ao que disse sobre o exemplo. Tentei escrever um exemplo simples considerando o projeto maior, que não é sobre saudações. Meu código se baseou no que aprendi lendo esse [texto](http://blog.caelum.com.br/reaproveitando-codigo-com-javascript-heranca-e-prototipos/). De todo modo, de acordo com o seu código, eu não tenho o método _greeting() na classe Pai, então, não houve sobrescrita na classe Filho, concorda? Como a pergunta é sobre a sobrescrita, agradeço muito o tempo dispensado, mas ainda não alcancei o meu objetivo.

Comment: @Leikovsk tem toda razão, foi um erro meu de atenção, a verdade é que a variável _greet da classe pai deveria se chamar _greeting, só que alterando ela o código volta a não funcionar, a noite darei uma olhada.

Comment: Discordo totalmente da parte da herança. A forma como ele fez é correta, e atribuir outra função diretamente como prototype (`this.prototype = Greet`) está errado e não gera herança nenhuma.

Comment: Sim @bfavaretto, eu acreditava que fosse devido a herança, mas acabei passando batido na variável `_greeting`, e foi o que me fez achar que o problema fosse aquele método, peço desculpas por isso. Mas em relação a linha `this.prototype = Greet`, ela gera sim herança, tanto que o texto é devidamente preenchido ao final de tudo.

Comment: Eu quis dizer que o que é herdado em `this.prototype = Greet` não tem efeito no resultado, mesmo no seu exemplo. Porque Greet não tem nenhum método, então nada é herdado dali. E disse "errado" porque atribuir uma função construtora como protótipo de outra quebra a cadeia de protótipos.

Answer (score 1):

Reescrevi o código pensando no problema e usando as dicas passadas:

```js
    var inheritance = function(father, child) {
     var fatherCopy = Object.create(father.prototype);
     child.prototype = fatherCopy;
     child.prototype.constructor = child;
    }

    var Parent = function(msg) {
        this.text = msg;
    }
    Parent.prototype.message = function() {
     return this.text;
    }
    var Oi = new Parent('Olá ');
    alert(Oi.message()); //Exibe "Olá"
       
    var Child = function(nome) {
     Parent.call(this, 'Olá ');
     this.text2 = nome;
    }
    inheritance(Parent, Child);
    Child.prototype.message = function() {
     return this.text + ' ' + this.text2;
    }
       
    var Ai = new Child('Fulano');
    alert(Ai.message()); //Exibe "Olá Fulano"
```

Problema resolvido.

Comment: Show @Leikovsk! No caso então a solução foi definir o `prototype` fora da classe?

Comment: @FabianoLothor para o problema apresentado, sim. Mas não resolve o problema real que tenho aqui. Acreditei que simplificando o problema resolveria o problema principal, mas me enganei. Existem particularidades que não descrevi nesse problema aqui. Estou pensando em publicar outra demanda em breve.

Comment: Eu fiquei curioso desde que li tua pergunta, pra mim, não faz sentido os prototypes conseguirem ser modificados `apenas` se forem definidos fora da classe, deve ter algo que não estamos enxergando.

Comment: Poste sim outra pergunta @Leikovsk :)